# Reading video with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm trying to read video from file
It seems like video is opened, but i can't read frames:

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.0.0'
>>>
>>> video = cv2.VideoCapture('action-recognition-train/0000.avi')
>>> video.isOpened()
True 
>>> nFrames = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
>>> print "frame number: %s" %nFrames
frame number: 166
>>> fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
>>> print "FPS value: %s" %fps
FPS value: 25.0
>>> height = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
>>> width = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
>>> print "video size:", height, 'x', width
video size: 240.0 x 320.0
>>> video.read()
(False, None)
```

reading from web-cam with cv2.VideoCapture(0) is ok

Comment: Internals of video files can be very complex - knowing this is an AVI file only narrows things down a little. I don't recognise the problem with CV2 (my video experience is with other tools). However, to help someone else answer, perhaps show the video stream type got from `ffprobe` or `mediainfo` - or simply link the source of your video if it is public. Chances are that the specific codecs and other choices inside the video file are affecting you getting the frames.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is to extract the frames and store it in a directory.
One can use ffmpeg to do it. After installing ffmpeg, do the following command from python:

os.system("ffmpeg -i path_to_video -r 1 path_to store/video_name%4d.jpg")

Here, -r is the rate at which frames are to be extracted from the video.
-r 1 means extract frames at 1fps.

After storing the video frames, we can list it and use the individual frames as required.